# Prevent Excel from resizing graphs

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

When a row or column is inserted around a graph in Excel, Excel automatically resizes (expands) the graph. This corrupts the dimensions I determine for a specific graph. How can I prevent Excel from doing this resizing officiousness for **all documents** (i.e. existing and new ones) as default?

Answer (score 11):

From Excel 2007 help:

> 1. Click anywhere in the chart.
> 2. This displays the chart tools, adding the Design, Layout, and Format tabs.
> 3. On the Format tab, in the Size group, click the Dialog Box Launcher (little square on the lower right corner of the group) next to Size.
> 4. On the Properties tab, under Object Positioning select the option that you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this applies to just the relevant graph or worksheet. What I need is to apply this as default to all new and existing Excel documents. Is it possible?

Comment: Not that I know of. There may be ways to do it in VBA, but that's not my forte. You could save your chart options as a template though:
Chart Tools>Design>Save as Template.